# Handling 'underscores' and special characters in latex listing package

Tags: listings

How to handle the 'underscore' and the special character in latex listing. I am working on a simple prolog style code

```
\begin{lstlisting}[label=LE, name=R_E]
    $\alpha_{1}$ = *M1*  °h1°(^A^, ^B^) :- °b1,1°(^B^, ^A^), °b1,2°(X).
    $\alpha_{2}$ = *M2*  °h2°(^A^, ^B^) :- °b2,1°(^B^, ^A^), °b2,2°(X).
\end{lstlisting}
```

This produces an output as shown below:

[image]

Below is my latex listing command:

```
\lstset{language=Prolog,
numbers=left, numberstyle=\scriptsize, numbersep=3pt,
basicstyle=\scriptsize \ttfamily,
tabsize=3,
captionpos=t,
stepnumber=1,
frame=lines,
breaklines=true,
showspaces=false,
commentstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily \color{mygreen},
moredelim=**[is][\color{vc}]{°}{°}, % To use text color inside a listing, we use a dilimiter
moredelim=**[is][\color{kw}]{*}{*},
moredelim=**[is][\color{darkgreen}]{^}{^},
%moredelim=**[is][\color{cyan}]{<?}{?>},
keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
morekeywords={type,value,href,xmlns,owl,/owl,rdf,/rdf,date,source,start,id,name,language,as, refersTo},
morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
morecomment=[s][\color{grey}]{<<}{>>}
escapeinside={} 
}
```

But its not printing the character 'α' nor the underscore next to it. Similaryl, also next to 'h' and further 'b'

Answer (score 0):

Using 'mathescape'

```
\begin{lstlisting}[label=LE, name=R_E, mathescape]
    $\alpha_{1}$ = *M1*  °h1°(^A^, ^B^) :- °b1,1°(^B^, ^A^), °b1,2°(X).
    $\alpha_{2}$ = *M2*  °h2°(^A^, ^B^) :- °b2,1°(^B^, ^A^), °b2,2°(X).
\end{lstlisting}
```